# How to import Drive API Client Library for Java and Google Sheets API version 3.0

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

After weeks of struggling with the documentation and plenty of forums I found out how to use both the Drive API Client Library for Java and Google Sheets API. I feel that the documentation especially for android is very lacking so I thought it would be useful to make a post explaining how to import the API's for Android. This is the post I wish I could have found when I started with these two libraries, I hope this helps someone who might have run into my problems..

Comment: Here's the reference of Drive API Client Library for Java: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2 and Google Sheets API: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/

Comment: "This is the post I wish I could have found" <- where can I find this post?

Comment: @Nurpax So sorry for the incomplete post, i thought i had posted the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: this is for Android only, and directed for Android Studio. The configuration descirbed below is what i am using, although there may be some unnecessary files included it does nonetheless work.* 
So first, the functionality that importing these two APIS will give is access to a users Google Drive, and to edit Google Spreadsheets on that account. There are two "versions" of the Drive API for Android, one made specifically for [Android](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/) and another for any [Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2) environment. Although the one made specifically for Android is simpler to use and is better integrated with Android it has one major drawback.
 `Note: The Google Drive Android API currently only supports drive.file and drive.appfolder authorization scopes. If your application requires additional permissions or features not yet available in the Drive Android API, you must use the Google APIs Java Client.`
 This means your app can only access and edit files it has itself created, for this reason i chose to use the Google APIs Java Client. As for the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#what_can_this_api_do) there are no real alternative versions, just itself.
Now the hardest time i had was trying to find out which files i needed to import, the documentation on this is hazey so here are the files needed.
Put all these files in the `app\libs` directory of your app. 
**To use Drive API Client Library for Java**
First "[Download the Drive API v2 Client Library for Java.](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2)" In `readme.html` it describes what dependencies are needed for android.
Use the following jars.

```
`google-api-client-android-1.19.1.jar (for SDK >= 2.1)
 google-http-client-android-1.19.0.jar 
 gson-2.1.jar
 protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar`
```

Also include `google-api-services-drive-v2-rev161-1.19.1.jar`
**To use Google Sheets API version 3.0**
Download gdata library from [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list), this includes spreadhseet jars and other gdata libraries like maps, finance, docs, calendar, etc..
In the gdata\java\lib use the following files.

```
`

    gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar
    gdata-core-1.0.jar
    gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar
    gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0.jar
    google-api-client-1.19.1.jar
    google-api-client-android-1.19.1.jar
    google-api-services-drive-v2-rev158-1.19.1.jar
    google-http-client-1.19.0.jar
    google-http-client-android-1.19.0.jar
    google-http-client-gson-1.19.0.jar
    google-oauth-client-1.19.0.jar
    guava-18.0.jar
    jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
    jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar
    jsr305.jar
    protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar
    gdata-base-1.0.jar
    gdata-client-1.0.jar

`
```

Download [javamail](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list), this is made specifically for android`

```
mail.jar 
activation.jar 
activation.jar`
```

Now that you have all these in your app\lib directory your build.gradle should include the following(add these in yourself):`

```
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/gdata-base-1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/gdata-client-1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/gdata-core-1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar')
compile files('libs/gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.19.1.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.19.1.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev158-1.19.1.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.19.0.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.19.0.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-gson-1.19.0.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.19.0.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.1.jar')
compile files('libs/guava-18.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar')
compile files('libs/jsr305.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
compile files('libs/protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar')`
```

**Final step!** 
 Because of the sheer number of methods that these imported jars have we need to make our app multi-dexable, this process is very straight forward and is described [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).Once you've done this your all set to start using the Drive and Spreadsheets API, if you found this useful up vote so other can see!

Comment: This is about what libraries you import into your project but it doesn't really explain how these are plugged together. For example, you can make a spreadsheet local to your device and access it without a network connection.  Can you accomplish this with the above APIs?  It'd be really nice to be able to edit local spreadsheets and have Android's own Drive functionality take care of cloud syncing.

Comment: As you stated, this post is about what jars to import, i never meant for this to be a post on how to use the respective APIs or exhaustively list their functionality. If you want to learn more about the APIs i feel that all the necessary documentation is available, they are linked in my answer.

Comment: Strangely, when I visited the gdata library link you mentioned for Sheets API v3, I found old versions of jars (like gdata-spreadsheet-1.0.jar instead of gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar). Same link is provided in Official Sheets API documentation. It caused lot of "method not found errors" :( and I couldn't find the reason until I came across this post. Others please make sure you are using latest versions of jars !!

Comment: here is the link to latest spreadsheet api jar - http://storage.googleapis.com/gdata-java-client-binaries/gdata-samples.java-1.47.1.zip

Comment: If you have something like this in you gradle build file you don't need to enumerate everything you put in the lib folder: `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` (as it is actually by default at least nowadays)