# The method setColCount(int) is undefined for the type WorksheetEntry

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-sheets

I want to integrate Google Drive (to create folders and spreadsheets) and Sheets API (to populate spreadsheets) in Android without using Account Manager for authentication. Hence I am using [Drive API v2 Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2) for drive integration and [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) for spreadsheets. I have successfully implemented OAuth2.0 authentication and drive integration (Create folders and spreadsheets), however I am unable to use Sheet API due to "x method is undefined for y" type of errors.

I authorized Sheet API Service  as follows :

```
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("Aplication-name");
service.setAuthSubToken(credential.getAccessToken());
```

I am able to print the list of spreadsheets.However, when I try to edit the worksheet dimensions, using setColCount(int) and setRowCount(int), it shows following error :

> The method setColCount(int) is undefined for the type WorksheetEntry
>
> The method setRowCount(int) is undefined for the type WorksheetEntry

But as per [Sheets API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/worksheets), the methods should work as follows :

```
    // Get the first worksheet of the first spreadsheet.
    // TODO: Choose a worksheet more intelligently based on your
    // app's needs.
    WorksheetFeed worksheetFeed = service.getFeed(
        spreadsheet.getWorksheetFeedUrl(), WorksheetFeed.class);
    List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets = worksheetFeed.getEntries();
    WorksheetEntry worksheet = worksheets.get(0);

    // Update the local representation of the worksheet.
    worksheet.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("Updated Worksheet"));
    worksheet.setColCount(5);
    worksheet.setRowCount(15);

    // Send the local representation of the worksheet to the API for
    // modification.
    worksheet.update();
```

I am able to use worksheet.getColCount() and worksheet.getRowCount() methods but the set methods are not working.

I have imported following JARs for Drive integration as per instructions given [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v2) :

> google-api-client-1.20.0.jar
>
> google-oauth-client-1.20.0.jar
>
> google-http-client-1.20.0.jar
>
> jsr305-1.3.9.jar
>
> google-http-client-jackson2-1.20.0.jar
>
> jackson-core-$2.1.3.jar
>
> google-api-client-android-1.20.0.jar (for SDK >= 2.1)
>
> google-http-client-android-1.20.0.jar

and following JARs for Sheets integration instructions given [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/setup):

> gdata-appsforyourdomain-1.0
>
> gdata-base-1.0
>
> gdata-calendar-1.0
>
> gdata-client-1.0
>
> gdata-codesearch-1.0
>
> gdata-photos-1.0
>
> gdata-spreadsheet-1.0
>
> guava-11.0.2
>
> jsr305
>
> javax.mail

Can it be because of some kind of conflicts between imported JARs?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of frustration, I finally noticed that the download link in the Official Sheets API documentation has obsolete spreadsheet api jar (gdata-spreadsheet-1.0.jar instead of gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar). You can download  gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar from [this](http://storage.googleapis.com/gdata-java-client-binaries/gdata-samples.java-1.47.1.zip) link. (Extract zip and go to java\libs folder). Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28993646/3148266) SO post for list of jar files to import.